# Serializadores anidados en django no muestra la relacion

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-urls

Tengo el codigo

```
    # API DQO
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sample
        fields = ['id']

class LoteDQOSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        sample_r = SampleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        model = models.LoteDQO
        fields = ['muestra_id', 'sample_r']

class DQO5Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lote_r = LoteDQOSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.DQO5
        fields = ['id', 'fecha', 'rcr', 'lote_r']


class DQO5ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.DQO5.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
```

pero solo recibo

> HTTP 200 OK Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept
>
> [
> {
> "id": 1,
> "fecha": "2016-11-10",
> "rcr": 100.0064
> },
> {
> "id": 2,
> "fecha": "2016-11-22",
> "rcr": 92.928
> },

Es decir esperaba los campos id del lote y la muestra.

Mis modelos son:

```
   class LoteDQO(BaseBatch):
    # Relación genérica al sample
    param_samples = GenericRelation('common.ParamSampleBatch',
                                    related_query_name='dqo_batch')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.fecha}"
    @atomic
    def unlink_sample(self, sample):
        # Eliminar todos los detalles
        try:
            sample.dqo5.delete()
        except DQO5.DoesNotExist:
            pass

class Sample(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('control', 'empresa')

    control = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    dqo_aplica = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     dqo = models.ForeignKey('hibasa_app.LoteDQO', null=True, blank=True,
                            related_name='muestras', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

## Control rutinario

```
class DQO5(models.Model):
    muestra = models.OneToOneField('Muestra', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lote_r")
rcr = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name='RECOBRO criterio 90-110% recuperacion')
```

Comment: Podrías compartir por favor tus modelos.

Comment: listo, edite la descrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione usando serializers.IntegerField(source=

```
# API DQO
class DQO5erializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.DQO5
        fields = '__all__'

    batch_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='muestra.dqo_id', read_only=True)
```

Por mis modelos no era necesario hacer varios serializadores anidados